# Any faster method?

Tags: chess

Manhattan distance is used to the center in chess code that uses an 0x88 board .

0x88 board is 128 square.

```
public static final byte DISTANCE[] = {
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 7, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 6, 5, 6, 
        7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 7, 6, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 6, 5, 4, 
        3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
        6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 6, 5, 4, 
        3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 
        0, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 
        2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 7, 6, 
        5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
        7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 
        2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
        7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 
        6, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 6, 5, 6, 
        7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 7, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    };
```

Is there any other faster method instead of 0x88 to find distance?

Comment: Basic mathematics? If you don't understand how to calculate the manhattan distance you need to go back and read those articles on manhattan distance because they said how to calculate it.

Comment: In simple words manhattan distance is going squares of corners,I got that. Any other faster method?

Comment: You're new to this site. I suggest you have a look at other up-voted questions to understand how to ask good questions. Good questions get excellent answers.

Answer (score 2):

#### To make sure you know how Manhattan Distance works

Manhattan distance is the sum of the total difference along each axis. In regular geometry you use Pythagoras' theorem:

[image]

where ***a*** and ***b*** are the difference along the ***x*** and ***y*** axes, and ***c*** is the total distance between the points.

In Taxicab geometry you don't need to square it. It's extremely simple. The distance between one point and another is just the sum of the distance along each axis. In 2D:

***x difference*** + ***y difference*** = ***Manhattan distance***

#### The fast method to calculate this

Create a function which takes two points and calculates the above. If you don't know how to do that, you need to go find a tutorial and start learning your programming language through it.

Comment: +1 for not banging your head against the wall after reading his comment :D